# XAMMP Sendmail issue

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail, phpmailer

I am having an issue getting my sendmail to work in Xammp.

The mail was working perfectly when using sendtodisk but now I get a crash log using sendmail:

### PHP to send emails (Using PHP Mailer):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->setFrom($from_email, 'Thomas ****');

$mail->addAddress('thomas@****.co.za', 'Client');

$mail->Subject = 'Sign Offs';

$mail->Body = generateMailTemplate($job_id, $to_email, $from_email, $name);

$mail->addAttachment('tmp/'.$job_id.'.pdf');
$mail->isHTML(true);  

if (!$mail->send()) {
    return $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

### php.ini

```
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

### sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=outbound.mailhop.org
smtp_port=25
```

### crash.log

```
command line      : C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -fthomas@****.co.za
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to look in your sendmail logs to see what's up. I'd recommend using SMTP to localhost as it's much easier to debug, and may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

try to set smtp settings for your phpmailer script, not for php

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'outbound.mailhop.org';
$mail->Port = 25;
// if need auth
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Body = 'body';
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Already tried this myself and it didn't seem to help.

The problem to me seems to be this: command line      : C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -fthomas@****.co.za

But I dont see why there is no space between the f and the email

Comment: There doesn't need to be a space after `-f`. You can add one if you like, but it won't help.